# Javascript form submits to new page -- how can I keep it on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html

beginner programmer here.  Trying to create a *very* primitive "chat interface", in JSP where I type in some words, they're stored in an array, then, ideally, spit back out on the same page.  I've got the code somewhat working, but it loads to a new page.

I've tried a number of different things that I read on the net, including trying to add "return false" to my `showChats` function, trying to change the submit to a button and doing "onclick", but it's still not working, always loads a new page.  Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance. Here's the code:

```
<script>

counter = 0;

//Array containing initial elements.
var chats = [];

function show_array(array) {
    array[counter] = document.getElementById("chatlet").value;
    for (x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
        document.write(array[x] + "<br/>");
    }
    counter++;
}

</script>

<form action="agenda2.jsp" method="get" onsubmit="show_array(chats)" >
    <p>
        <textarea id="chatlet" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Chat">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight: Huh? OP basically don't want to submit any form. How can altering the form's request method have any influence on *not* submitting a form?

Comment: Add a `return false;` to the end of your `show_array` method (this will prevent the form from submitting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `return` keyword with `onsubmit` like `onsubmit="return show_array(chats)"` and then `return false` in the JS function.

**Code:**

```
<form action="agenda2.jsp" method="get" onsubmit="return show_array(chats)" >
```

**JS**

```
counter = 0;
var chats = [];
function show_array(array) {
    array[counter] = document.getElementById("chatlet").value;
    for (x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        document.write(array[x] + "<br/>");
    }
    counter++;
    return false;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KImjB)**

Comment: This worked for me!  I had forgotten to add the return to the onsubmit!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the end of your function show_array() you have to add return false; Or in other case you might concider using jQuery and do this:

Give your form a class or id

```
<form class="myform">
....
</form>

<script>
    $("myform").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();   
    });
</script>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Using query you could do below

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: 'get form data',
        success: function (res) {
            // handle response here
        }
    });
});
```